# Ruby on Rails Name-spacing Standards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

What is currently the standard for namespacing resources in rails.

```
Request
Food
Clothing
Request::Food
Request::Clothing
```

I have this models in my app and I encountered some issues with having a namespace with an existing resource like `Request`.

I've found an article regarding this scenario and it suggested to have it pluralized(ex: `Requests::Food`. [Here is the link for the article](https://blog.bullettrain.co/rails-model-namespacing/).
Is this still recommended until now or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What issues did you encounter? Is `Request` a class or a module?

Comment: `Request` is a class.

Comment: are `Food` and `Clothing` activerecord models, or just plain old ruby dclasses

Comment: @LesNightingill All of those are active record models. `Request::Food, Request::Clothing` is an STI pointing to `Food, Clothing` simultaneously. Also `Request` is an active record model.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to use `Request` as the resource (ActiveRecord class) and `Requests` as the namespace (plain Ruby module) holding additional resources. Even though it's probably possible to re-use the class as a namespace, I'd prefer to have this kind of distinction to avoid problems. (Rails can be quite picky)